# Silly problem with bassistance jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

The there guys.

I'm confused with a strange behavior of a simple page using bassistance jquery validation. In short, I have two input fields, both marked as "required". The problem is that it seems that the plugin is validation only the first field.

This is the snippet of my test:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="[path to my app]/js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="[path to my app]/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <form id="testForm">
   <input id="field1" type="text" class="required"/>
   <input id="field2" type="text" class="required"/>

   <button>Query</button>
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#testForm").validate();
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I click on the Query button, a (correctly shown) error message is presented to the first field, but not to the second one.

Maybe one of you knows what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

Your input fields must have names:

```
<input id="field1" name="field1" type="text" class="required" />
<input id="field2" name="field2" type="text" class="required" />
```

And here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GZzGj/).

Comment: Exactly. I had a similar problem and it took a while to find the problem. Especially since it wasn't my HTML code to start with.

Comment: Thanks Darin and Bernard. This is embarrassing. This is the kind of problems I get after 30 days outside the office :-) Thank you guys!